# Get public (remote) IP address

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if there was a simple way to get the public IP address of a computer using Ruby.

Comment: Fetch [whatismyip](http://www.whatismyip.com/) and parse it. :)

Comment: what information do you have in hand ? the domain name ? If the user is directly connecting to your server .. then the client ip is the public ip

Comment: Where is the code going to run, on the end user's computer? are they talking to an external server already (IE web request)

Comment: I'm just after the public IP.  I just want code that displays the public IP of the the computer running the code.@Sergio thanks, will look into parsing it.

Comment: This website: http://208.91.135.51/posts/show/13567 suggests a seemingly nice way to do it.

Comment: http://checkip.dyndns.org is easier to parse

Comment: @Mischa the answer in this post yields the local IP address

Comment: @padde, yeah, I see that now. The accepted answer doesn't seem to match the question, which is about the public IP address. So in a sense, this question *is* a duplicate.

Comment: @Mischa it is not a duplicate! In the other question, the poster asks about getting the ip adress of the requester in a ruby on rails app. The above question is about getting one own's remote ip address!

Comment: What?  How did my question get closed???  I searched before postin to make sure it wasn't a duplicate and that link links to a question that wants to find the private IP.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Akamai provides a "What is my IP" page that you can fetch:

```
require 'open-uri'
remote_ip = open('http://whatismyip.akamai.com').read
```

There are a few alternatives that do the same thing, though:

- http://whatismyip.akamai.com
- http://ipecho.net/plain
- http://icanhazip.com
- http://ident.me
- http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com

You can also use the `ipv4` and `ipv6` subdomains with `icanhazip.com`.

If you don't want to depend on a third party, you can roll your own in a one-line rack app and deploy this for free on Heroku or whatever. It takes into account that `X-Forwarded-For` may contain a comma separated list of proxy IP addresses and only returns the client IP.

```
# config.ru

run lambda { |env|
  remote_ip = env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] || env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  remote_ip = remote_ip.scan(/[\d.]+/).first
  [200, {'Content-Type'=>'text/plain'}, [remote_ip]] 
}
```

Comment: Or do `require 'open-uri'; puts open('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp').read
`

Comment: @roychri useful service! It seems to be awfully slow for me, though. `curl ifconfig.me/ip` takes about 6.0s while my service (`curl remote-ip.herokuapp.com`) takes an average of about 0.3s. Akamai (`curl whatismyip.akamai.com`) can of course leverage their vast network and give me an unbeaten response time of about 0.1s. All data is averaged over 50 requests from a generally fast and stable internet connection in Germany.

Comment: Hi I added the latest run lambda code and it's still returning my internal IP address of 10.0.2.2 when I am expecting it to return my public IP address. It appears to work from your demo link am I doing something wrong? I added it to the config.ru file and restarted the server. Added it right before run::Application line.

Comment: Hi are you running it locally? You need to deploy it on a remote server.

Answer (score 7):

No scraping necessary!

I use [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/), an open api that returns your public ip address. Useful if you want a json response (not shown here).

```
require 'net/http'
public_ip = Net::HTTP.get URI "https://api.ipify.org"
=> "12.34.56.78"
```

Or with curl:

```
public_ip = `curl https://api.ipify.org`
=> "12.34.56.78"
```

Don't get excited, that's not my public ip address :)

Answer (score 2):

I use curl:

```
my_ip = `curl http://ipecho.net/plain`
```

This does not use Ruby stdlib and requires curl though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a service such as http://www.whatsmyip.website/ to programatically obtain the IP. Using something like Linux curl would automatically just return the IP, but if you use a different application/ language you may need to check out their API.

```
ip = `curl http://www.whatsmyip.website`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same problem and found great solution API based.

To get the public IP address we can can use the below code:

```
require "net/http"

ip = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://api.ipify.org"))
puts "My public IP Address is: " + ip
```

API Site Url: `https://www.ipify.org/`

It's too late to asnwer on this but I thought it may be halpful for others.

Comment: @jpalmieri gave the same answer some year before [here below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31016983/1498118)